# Implementing Transactions in SSIS Package for a Data flow task

Tags: ssis

I am trying to implement transactions in SSIS using Transaction option property and also enabled DTC.

The issue that I am facing is, Data flow task (It loads stage table) inside a sequence container is running continuously and not ending or throwing an error if I update the Transaction option to Required at Sequence container level, Supported at Package level and Task level

Can someone help me in fixing this issue.

I have tried changing transaction option properties at different levels like Package, Sequence Container and task level to fix the issue but it didn't work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your data flow ? the error that you are having ?

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the Data flow task in the above question. Actually package is not throwing any error but the Data flow tasks runs continuously and doesn't stop if I update the Transaction option to Required at Sequence container level, Supported at Package level and Task level